# Ubuntu 22.04 xorg won't start, how to reconfigure just Xorg?

Tags: drivers, 22.04, xorg, nvidia-geforce

My oldish laptop has been running fine on Kubuntu 18.04 for many years. The battery lasts between 1 second and 1 minute, and after an unplanned power loss shutdown, the main and external monitor displays were not very workable. App windows would only show on the laptop, display manager items showed only the external monitor screen, mouse could move between both, external monitor was not shown by the displays app but some things were shown on it. I tried to figure it out, but then figured let's upgrade to 20.04.

It was still not right, so let's upgrade to 22.04.  Voila, it worked, however I had to `startx` manually. It only booted into a TTY screen, but just plain `startx` at the command line worked.

I made it go downhill from there, and I'm not sure what all I did. I  probably only needed to relearn which startup file to edit and have it start the display manager and Xorg. I  tried `lightdm` instead of `sddm`, tried different Nvidia drivers or the open source driver, tried removing xconf files to let it reconfigure the correct settings. Now there's zero response, `startx` just freezes, and not even keyboard works.

Is there a way to have Xorg start fresh like with a USB ISO?  Booting from USB, everything does fine.  Or remove and reinstall Xorg configuration and display drivers without hosing the whole OS?

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF106M [GeForce GT 445M] (rev a1)
```

Here's the [xorg log file](https://pastebin.com/2igMTEzV).

`apt update` and `upgrade` are all up to date, no broken or missing packages that `apt` knows of.

What `startx` results in is a screen with a square sad face and:

> Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again.

At this point *Log Out* button, mouse or keyboard inputs are not functional.

Specific errors from the log file, they say the error usually gives the instruction how to fix, but still not clear what to do...

```
[ 351.196] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:02:00.0: -19 
[ 351.197] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory 
[ 351.197] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting 
[ 351.197] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory

[   351.203] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   351.203]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 0.0.2
[   351.203]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   351.203] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[   351.203] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   351.203] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   351.203] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   351.203] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so

[   351.203] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   351.203]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 0.0.2
[   351.203]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   351.203] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[   351.203] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   351.203] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   351.203] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   351.203] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   351.203] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[   351.203] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[   351.203] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
```

Comment: All set.  Not really a 'Solution', but I'm done messing with it.  I just did a whole fresh install. It wasn't that hard to re-learn how to set up a couple of things on the system.